# how to get element from an component using protractor element by css

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor

I need to click at all "checkbox" from an element. I've trying using element.all(by.css)
but I don't know who to pass the path to my css.

I'm trying:

```
 for(let index = 0; index < limit; index ++){ 
    const check = element.all(by.css('input[type=checkbox]')).get(index); 
    check.click();  
}
```

But I need to click those check from an particular panel: **p-tabpanel with header ="Cargo") OR all the input checkbox by the id= ui-tabpanel-6**

**How can I pass the whole path to my css?**

HTML

```
<p-tabpanel _ngcontent - c32="" header="Cargo">

    <div class="ui-tabview-panel ui-widget-content ng-star-inserted ui-helper-hidden" 
        role="tabpanel" id="ui-tabpanel-6" 
        aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="ui-tabpanel-6-label">

        <label _ngcontent - c34="" class="control-label-radio">
            <input _ngcontent - c34="" type="checkbox"> Conhecimento - Escolaridade - Nível superior em Administração
        </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

> But I need to click those check from an particular panel: p-tabpanel with header ="Cargo"

Add `header ="Cargo"` as the root to form a nested selector:

```
css('p-tabpanel[header=Cargo] input[type=checkbox]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `element.all().map()` to return `checkbox click` promise array. Then use `Promise.all(<promise array>)` to wait the click on all checkbox complete.

```
let promiseList = element.all(
        by.css('p-tabpanel[header="Cargo"] input[type=checkbox')
    )
    .map((it)=>{
        return it.click();
    });

Promise.all(promiseList)
// Promise is native API of nodejs > 8, please use nodejs 8 or higher.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code:

```
element.all(by.css('input[type=checkbox]'))
.then(function (allCheckBoxes) {
  for(let i=0;i<allCheckBoxes.length;i++){
   allCheckBoxes[i].click();
  }
}
```

We get a promise of all the checkboxes and then we iterate over them and click them one by one.